# How to avoid multiple requests for a site with many images

Tags: image, hover

I have a page with hundreds of images that I want to show only on hover over text.
I did it using CSS, but the page loads very slowly because it has over 700 images.

How can I twist it to load images only at the time of hovering instead of when I load the page?

The page is http://play-well.ro/comp

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to supply more details---what code you have already, what you have tried, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) to merge small images into a single file (this way you will avoid multiple HTTP requests to fetch the images)

and you should also consider paginating the contents of the page itself to improve the performance in general